# Plotting sections through plane

Tags: plotting

I have given the following function:

```
B[x_] := Sqrt[x^2 - (9 - 3 x)^2]
```

where x is also dependent of several cos-function. All in all I wanna plot the following function:

```
ContourPlot[
 B[1/2 (Cos[Subscript[k, x]] + 
     2*Cos[Subscript[k, x]/2]*Cos[Sqrt[3] Subscript[k, z]/2] + 
     6)], {Subscript[k, x], -6 Pi/3, 6 Pi/3}, {Subscript[k, 
  z], -6 Pi/3, 6 Pi/3}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameTicks -> {Pi/3 Range[-6, 6], Pi/3 Range[-6, 6]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"k_x", "k_z"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The plot is looking like this: [image: Contour Plot]
But now I wanna plot sections (or cuts) through the plane. I tried to calculate this:

```
Solve[B[1/
 2 (Cos[Subscript[k, x]] + 
  2*Cos[Subscript[k, x]/2]*Cos[Sqrt[3] Subscript[k, z]/2] + 6)] == Pi/2, {Subscript[k, x], Subscript[k, z]}]
```

But all I got was this solution:

```
Plot[-((2 ArcCos[
1/8 (7 Cos[Subscript[k, x]/2] - 8 Cos[Subscript[k, x]/2]^3 - Sqrt[
   81 Cos[Subscript[k, x]/2]^2 - 
    2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[Subscript[k, x]/2]^2]) Sec[Subscript[k, x]/
  2]^2])/Sqrt[3]), {Subscript[k, x], -10, 10}]
```

with a plot that doesn't look right at all:

[image: Plot2]

In the end I expect something that is comparable to this:

[image: Comparison]

How can I plot sections through plane (cuts through levels), so that I get curves in 2D-space?

Comment: What is `B2` supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry all ´B2´ is ´B´. I correct that.

Comment: You can still use `ContourPlot[]` for plotting isolated slices: `ContourPlot[B[(Cos[kx] + 2 Cos[kx/2] Cos[Sqrt[3] kz/2] + 6)/2] == π/2, {kx, -6 π/3, 6 π/3}, {kz, -6 π/3, 6 π/3}]`.

Comment: Ah so simple, so true. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to  @J.M. who needs help.

```
ContourPlot[
 B[(Cos[kx] + 2 Cos[kx/2] Cos[Sqrt[3] kz/2] + 6)/2] == π/2
 , {kx, -6 π/3, 6 π/3}
 , {kz, -6 π/3, 6 π/3}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]